# How can I replace text between two values without regex?

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I would like to replace text between two values not by using regex. I want the user to define which values he/she will find text between by using two text boxes. So far this is what I wrote. It is working accept for just a small bug I have been trying to get rid of for hours.

```
        string rw = richTextBox2.Text;
        string s = richTextBox1.Text;
        int start = s.IndexOf(textBox1.Text);
        int end = s.IndexOf(textBox2.Text);
        string textBefore = s.Substring(0, start);
        string textAfter = s.Substring(end + 1);
        string newText = rw;
        richTextBox1.Text = textBefore + newText + textAfter;
```

For example the value I wanted to replace is "hello (q) replacethis (qt) hello" and I want to replace everything between (q) and (qt) with "(q) replaced (qt)" so the result would turn out as "hello (q) replaced (qt) hello". But instead of the result turning out as I just explained, it turns out as "hello (q) replaced (qt)qt) hello". Why does this happen?

Comment: `s.Substring(end + 1);` starts from 1 character after the *start* of `(qt)`. You want something like `s.Substring(end + textBox2.Text.Length);`

Comment: it would help to debug each line to see exactly what is in each variable.

Comment: Something is a little confusing here... it would be nice to know which text box had your main string in it, and what text box (or two text boxes?) has your delimiters in.

Comment: oh... i was getting richTextBox2.Text mixed up with textBox2.Text

Comment: Why not use regex? This is exactly the kind of thing they're designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
string textAfter = s.Substring(end + 1);
```

with

```
string textAfter = s.Substring(end + richTextBox2.Text.Length);
```

You want to start counting the last segment of text after your final delimiter string, not at the start of your final delimiter string (or one after the start)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do as simply as this?

```
var original = "hello (q) replacethis (qt) hello";
var result = original.Replace("(q) replacethis (qt)", "(q) replaced (qt)");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This outputs:

> hello (q) replaced (qt) hello

Comment: D'oh !!    After seeing your answer, I'm kinda ashamed at my answer.  It is late at night, though, so i wasn't thinking clearly.